# Image and kernel of linear transformation. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$$X$ is linear space, and $f:X\to X$ is linear transformation.   Then:
**a.** $\im(f)\subset \im (f\circ f)$
**b.** $\ker (f)\subset \ker (f\circ f)$
**c.** $\ker(f)\cap \im(f)=\{0\}$
**My approach**:
Being honestly I can solve only **b.**
**b.**
Consider matrix $M$ for $f$  we have that matrix for $(f\circ f)$ is $M^2$. Therefore if $Ax=0$ then also $A^2x=A0=0$. Hence, $\ker(f)\subset \ker(f\circ f)$.

I ask for checking my solution for **b.** and help with rest of question.

Comment: Are you sure you may assume that $f$ can be represented as a matrix? Linear spaces can be infinite-dimensional and then there is no matrix “$M$ for $f$”? Moreover, are you sure you should show that the statements are true? Or should you rather check whether they are true? In the former case, have you copied them correctly?

Comment: Only answer true/false. However, some intution is good. I think that we may assume finit spaces.   Help me please, I have no idea how to sovle this one.

Comment: You should add to your question that you need to find out which is true and which is false. (b) looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$*Hint*. Try to construct linear space $X$ and a (simple) nontrivial linear map $f \colon X → X$ with $\ker f = \im f$. What does that imply for $f ∘ f$ and $\ker f ∩ \im f$? Find such a linear map $f$ in a linear space $X$ of a dimension as small as possible. (Can you go dimension zero or one?)

*Further*. You can construct a linear transformation of the two-dimensional $ℚ$-space $ℚ^2$ by specifying its action on the standard basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Now think of $ℚ^2$ as the Euclidean plane the linear map you want to construct as follows: Project the vertical axis “diagonally” onto the horizontal axis and the horizontal axis to zero, then linearly extend this map. Can you give the matrix for such a map?

Comment: I have no idea. Could you be more precisely ? I cant find such $f$ that $\ker f=im f$.

Comment: @HaskellFun I updated my answer.

Comment: so **c.** is false, and **a.** is false. Yeah ?