# Matrix, eigenvalues, linear independence - conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$  and vectors $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Aa=a, Ab=b, Ac=-c$.  Then:
**a.** $1$ and $-1$ are roots of characteristic polynomial of $A$.
**b.** vectors $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent.
**c.** vectors $a,b,c$ are linearly independent.
**My approach**
**a.** It is true, because of the fact that $Aa=1a$ is definition both eigenvalue and eigenvector.
**b.** yes, it is true - these vectors reference to distinct eigenvalues.
**c.** No, because $a,b$ reference to the same eigenvalue.

Can you check my solutions, please ?

Comment: Why is this question similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1928504/151595) one?

Comment: It is diffiuclt ot say.

Comment: False, false, false; it would be true, true, false if in the assumptions you have that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are **nonzero** vectors.